# How to create a matrix with different elements using Matlab

Tags: matlab

how to create 9×9 matrix with the first 3 rows all zeros, 4 to 6 rows are all filled with 5, and the remaining rows first elements are 1's and the remaining elements are 5's, using MATLAB?

Comment: @Guanxi: Obviously nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an answer that'll teach you how to use MATLAB if you're interested enough:

```
A = bsxfun(@times, ones(9), kron([0 5 5], [1 1 1])') - ...
    [kron([0 0 4], [1 1 1])' zeros(9,8)]
```

result:

```
A =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
     1     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
     1     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
     1     5     5     5     5     5     5     5     5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
subZero = zeros(3, 9);
subFive = 5*ones(3, 9);
subsubOnes = ones(3, 1);
subsubFive = 5*ones(3, 8);

subOneFive = [subsubOnes subsubFive];

yourMatrix = [subZero; subFive; subOneFive];
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating matrix with values at the time of initialization like this:

```
myMatrix = [...
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
    5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
    5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
    1 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
    1 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
    1 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5];
```

I know there are simpler ways to initialize.